# React Native: XCode: Build failed with error "EMFILE: too many open files, watch"

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native, apple-m1

– MackBook Air M1
– macOS 11.3
– XCode 12.5
– react native 0.64.1
– node 16.0.0
– npm 7.15.1
– watchman 2021.05.31.00

When I try to archive a project or build one for a device, Xcode stops building with an error:

```
/Users/aptyp/Projects/Proffmylife/Client/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/emhermesc.js:81
          throw ex;
          ^

Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:204:21)
Emitted 'error' event on NodeWatcher instance at:
    at NodeWatcher.checkedEmitError (/Users/aptyp/Projects/Proffmylife/Client/node_modules/sane/src/node_watcher.js:143:12)
    at FSWatcher.emit (node:events:365:28)
    at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:210:12) {
  errno: -24,
  syscall: 'watch',
  code: 'EMFILE',
  filename: null
}
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

But for the simulator, the build works fine.

I have tried to reinstall **node_modules**, **Pods**, **watchman** with **brew**. Also I've created files **limit.maxfiles.plist**, **limit.maxproc.plist** into dir **/Library/LaunchDaemons/** and now **ulimit -a** shows **processes 2000** and **file descriptors 524288**. Restarting computer and unlock Keychain.

On my PC with Hackintosh I don't have this problem.

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this issue?

Comment: Yes and no. I created a new project with the same name, installed all the latest packages and copied the code. Only after that the project was built success.

Comment: I think that this problem occurred to me due to the fact that I had previously updated the "react-native" package, but badly corrected the native platform files in the "ios" folder.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I created a new project with the same name, installed all the latest packages and copied the code. Only after that the project was built success.

Comment: does this count as a solution?

Comment: Found my solution at this issue's comment https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31094#issuecomment-796743154

Answer (score 1):

This error is because of a bug in module fsevents for mac m1 silicon. See the thread: https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/668

It got fixed with new version of watchman. Upgrade your watchman through brew. Delete your project and download from git and rebuild everything along with pod install and then it should archive no problem.

[Facebook guy admitting to the bug and fixing it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62aBc.png)