# Expo giving an error "EMFILE: too many open files..." for my react native and firebase app

Tags: node.js, firebase, react-native, expo, node-modules

This is the full error "Error: EMFILE: too many open files, watch
at FSEvent.FSWatcher._handle.onchange (node:internal/fs/watchers:207:21" The issue started after I installed an api (AsyncStorage) from react native. I uninstalled it, uninstalled all node modules, ran npm again, updated expo version, tried the unlimit stuff and nothing worked. There is people that say to "brew install watchman", I tried that but it does not work. Not familiar if watchman would work for me as am using Firebase for my backend only. I am using an M1 mac air 2020.

Any help on how to get expo working with be appreciated.

Comment: There are a lot is [very similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965606/node-and-error-emfile-too-many-open-files) here on SO. I would suggest looking through [those questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=EMFILE%3A+too+many+open+files) and their answers to see a if question has [already been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67837066/react-native-xcode-build-failed-with-error-emfile-too-many-open-files-watch)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.